# October CMS - Remove file attachments with unsaved model

Tags: php, octobercms

I'm trying to create a front-end AJAX file uploader for a form and everything is working perfect, except for one issue.

I used deferred binding to enable uploading before the record is created in DB.

In a rare scenario, when someone uploads a file and doesn't send the form the record is not created, but the attached file still exists.

I don't know if there is a build-in solution for this problem is October CMS.

A better example is RainLab Blog Plugin. If you try a new post and add a featured image but not save the post and close the tab, the post doesn't create but the file remains in storage/app/uploads/public.

I was thinking of writing an scheduled task to delete unbinded files, but don't know how to detect them.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look at the table:

```
system_files
```

and the ones without a 
**attachment_id** or/and 
**attachment_type** or/and 
**field**

are unused maybe the media table should be cleaned too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Seems like cleaning records with no attachment_id in 'system_files' table will do the work. I will try and write a plugin to remove the files. I wondered if the is some built-in solution for this problem, but seems like there is not.

Comment: For anyone interested in this question, I found a plugin that seems to do this, but I havn't tested it. http://octobercms.com/plugin/genius-storageclear

Comment: Be advised that the "Storage Cleaner" plugin seems not yet Laravel 5.5 compatible.